# What does blockchain.info wallet need your email for?

Tags: blockchain.info, wallet-security, mobile

*This question is related to the specific software product, but comments on the need for usage of an e-mail address in similar software products are welcomed.*

I installed blockchain.info wallet to my mobile device and it is all good, but it says in settings that I have unconfirmed e-mail. OK, I confirmed my e-mail, but now I'd like to know what it will be used for.

I can see 3 options:

1. Notifications
2. MFA
3. Password restoring

AFAIU, it is used for login to the web interface and [notifications](https://blockchain.info/wallet/payment-notifications). Would like to be sure if I am right about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the wallet settings in mobile app:

> Your verified email address is used to send login codes when suspicious or unusual activity is detected, to remind you of your wallet login ID, and to send bitcoin payment alerts when you receive funds.